# Instance level synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized, pool

if I have an Object Pool class like

```
public class ClassAPool 
{
    private final ClassA[] objects=new ClassA[10]
    private int current=0;
    public synchronized ClassA get()
    {
       ClassA instance;
       if(objects[current]==null)
       {
          objects[current]=new ClassA()
       }
       instance=objects[current];
       if(current==objects.length-1)
       {
          current=0;
       }else{
          current++;
       }
    }

}
```

And ClassA :

```
public class ClassA{
   public void doSomething()
   {
      .....
   }
}
```

And I want to use the Pool in another class and make method `doSomthing()` thread safe in each object.

is some think like this will work?

```
public class Test{
  ClassAPool pool;
  public void testMethod()
  {  
     ClassA instance=pool.get();
     synchronized(instance)
     {
       instance.doSomething();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean 'thread safe' as opposed to 'thread save'? If so, edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: The test method will 'correctly' synchronize on the fetched instance, whatever it is. Any object can function as a lock monitor -  it must just be the same monitor to create mutually exclusive execution.

Comment: There is no such thing as "thread safe" as a general property. Its always tied to a specific set of state, which must be defined. If the idea is to ensure that only one call per instance of ClassA executes, then you need to ensure all possible invocations of doSomething() do synchronize on the same object. Doing this by synchronizing explicitly before calling (like in testMethod()) is only practical if there are no other call sites. Its simpler and generally easier to understand if you simply put the synchronized on the *method* (doSomething()) in that case (harder to bypass by accident).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly let me tell you that I feel you are trying pretty hard (*which is really good thing*) but unfortunately your code looks like quite a mess and reading it doesn't really tell what and why you are trying to achieve, and most importantly there are many bugs like (*I hope you have not shown us all code, so may look a mess, but your all actual code is all cool*):

- `ClassAPool.get()` promises to return `ClassA` but there is no return statement.
- In `Test`, you are doing `pool.get();` but we don't see `pool` being instantiated.
- Etc...

---

Now coming to answer part, I would agree with @james that information and your objective (*given the code you have shown*) is not very clear so answering is difficult, but I hope my below points will help you solve your problem.

This is what you want:

> And I want to use the Pool in another class and make method
>   doSomthing() thread safe in each object.

Your `ClassAPool.get()` can possibly return 10 different objects of `ClassA`, and then in your `Test` class your are trying to synchronize based on object of `ClassA` returned from `ClassAPool.get()`.

Remember, **each object has only 1 lock which can be acquired and if threadA has acquired it then no other thread can acquire it until it is released by threadA.** But if there are 2 different objects then 2 different threads can acquire one lock of each object. So, in your are case since `ClassAPool.get()` can possibly return 10 different objects of `ClassA`, `synchronized(instance)` will not help much because 10 thread can possibly acquire 10 different locks from 10 different objects of `ClassA`, and hence 10 threads could possibly be running `doSomething()` at same time.

Yes, but if by "*doSomthing() thread safe in each object*" you mean that when `ClassA instance=pool.get();` return the old object of `ClassA` and some thread is executing `ClassA.doSomthing` and you wish synchronization then there is some possibility that you will see some synchronization with the code you have shown (*I said possibility because it depends on how many threads are requesting and each thread is using same instance of `ClassAPool`*).

On a side note, try using `Thread.sleep` in `doSomthing()` and print current thread id, which will give clear picture of what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

The pool has nothing to do with your question.  As far as I can tell, your question is about whether or not the `instance.doSomething()` call will be thread-safe.

There's not enough information here to answer the question, because the answer depends on what *data* `instance.doSomething()` might operate on.

If it only operates on fields of `instance`, then the one call that you showed us probably is "thread-safe", but you haven't told us that that is the only doSomething() call.  If there's another doSomething() call somewhere else in your code, then that call might *not* be thread safe.

Likewise, even the one call that you showed us will not be thread safe if there are two different instances whose `doSomething()` method might operate on the same shared data.